# Issue with Generating self-signed Certificate(X509), Private and Public key in Java Programatically

Tags: java, android, x509certificate, bouncycastle, self-signed

I am facing issues when i tried generating the certificate using BouncyCastle or Sun.Security.*

**Requirements-
Android API support - For API 15 and API 8**

I tried following ways to do it..

**1) I tried using BouncyCastle jar with the following code**

```
    X509V3CertificateGenerator v3CertGen = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();

    v3CertGen.setSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(new SecureRandom().nextInt()));

    v3CertGen.setIssuerDN(new X509Principal("CN=" + domainName + ", OU=None, O=None L=None, C=None"));
    v3CertGen.setNotBefore(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30));
    v3CertGen.setNotAfter(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365*10)));
    v3CertGen.setSubjectDN(new X509Principal("CN=" + domainName + ", OU=None, O=None L=None, C=None"));
    //        
    v3CertGen.setPublicKey(KPair.getPublic());
    v3CertGen.setSignatureAlgorithm("MD5WithRSAEncryption"); 

    X509Certificate PKCertificate = v3CertGen.generateX509Certificate(KPair.getPrivate());
```

**issues faced with this code:**

- CertificateGenerator is depricated
- X509V3CertificateGenerator class is not identified
- tried with different versions of bouncycastle jars (1.45, 1.46, 1.47 & 1.57)
- tried using CertificateBuilder (code is below)
- SubjectPublicKeyInfo this class is not identified when i used this code.

  ```
      SubjectPublicKeyInfo publicKeyInfo = 
      SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(kp.getPublic().getEncoded());

      X509v3CertificateBuilder myX509v3CertificateBuilder = new X509v3CertificateBuilder(new X500Name("c=sree"), BigInteger.valueOf(new Random().nextInt(1000000)), new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()), new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 *365 * 100)), new X500Name("c=sree"), publicKeyInfo);

      ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("Sha256withRSA").build(myCAPrivateKey);
      X509CertificateHolder certHolder = myX509v3CertificateBuilder.build(signer);
      X509Certificate cert = (new JcaX509CertificateConverter().getCertificate(certHolder));

      CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509", "BC");
      Certificate certcert = cf.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(cert.getEncoded()));
  ```

**2)** **I tried with Sun.Security.* package with the below code**

```
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import sun.security.tools.keytool.CertAndKeyGen;
import sun.security.x509.X500Name;

public class SelfSignedCertificateGeneration {
public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        CertAndKeyGen keyGen=new CertAndKeyGen("RSA","SHA1WithRSA",null);
        keyGen.generate(1024);

        //Generate self signed certificate
        X509Certificate[] chain=new X509Certificate[1];
        chain[0]=keyGen.getSelfCertificate(new X500Name("CN=ROOT"), (long)365*24*3600);

        System.out.println("Certificate : "+chain[0].toString());
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

**Issues faced with this code:**

- CertAndKeyGen and few other class are not accessible

**

***Is there any other way? please suggest me.***

**

Answer (score 2):

Old versions of android are shipped with a cut-down version of bouncycastle. So you can not trust that the functionality you need is complete. Try to include https://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/, a repackage of Bouncy Castle for Android.

Specify dependencies in gradle

```
compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.56.0.0'
compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.56.0.0'
compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:pkix:1.56.0.0'
compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:pg:1.56.0.0'
```

Package names have changed from `org.bouncycastle.*` to `org.spongycastle.*` and provider name from `BC` to `SC`

Here you have an example of [using spongycastle to create a selfsigned certificate](https://medium.com/@bouhady/self-sign-certificate-creation-using-spongy-castle-for-android-app-61f1545dd63)

Comment: This is not working @pedrofb again facing the same issue.

Comment: yes i am not able to compile the code. the error is (not able to identify the class) No.Class.defination found.

Comment: Is gradle working propertly? Is it downloading the dependencies and are `org.spongycastle.*` packages availables from your code?

Comment: I should be working on Eclipse. so, i downloaded the jars from link you mentioned and added. Shall the paste the error log here?

Comment: Do not paste code or traces in comments. Just edit your own question and add the relevant info